# Flutter: live stream with getx has a problem, it shows data without updating

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, flutter-getx

I use Getx package in my apps, it works beautiful, but when I tried to get the data from firestore in stream it gets the data but without stream, so my UI hasn't updated until I go to another page and reenter the page which has the data!!!

Actually it's a big problem to bring this data without streaming, each time I have to exit and reopen to update!!!

Here my controller class:

```
class AddSubscriberController extends GetxController {

final CollectionReference _subscribersCollectionRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Subscribers');

List<SubscriberModel> get subscriberModel => _subscriberModel;
  final List<SubscriberModel> _subscriberModel = [];
  RxList<SubscriberModel> subscribers = RxList([]);


  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    subscribers.bindStream(getSubscribers());
  }


  Stream<List<SubscriberModel>> getSubscribers() {
    return _subscribersCollectionRef
        .orderBy('Register date', descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .map((QuerySnapshot query) {
      for (var element in query.docs) {
        subscriberModel.add(SubscriberModel.fromMap(element));
      }
      return subscriberModel;
    });
  }
}
```

And here is my UI class:

```
Obx(() {
          AddSubscriberController controller =
              Get.put(AddSubscriberController());
          return ListView.builder(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: controller.subscribers.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return buildSubInfo(
                name: controller.subscribers[index].firstName,
                lastName: controller.subscribers[index].lastName,
                father: controller.subscribers[index].father,
                area: controller.subscribers[index].area,
                counterNo: controller.subscribers[index].counterNumber,
                date: controller.subscribers[index].date,
              );
            },
          );
        }), // Obx
```

How can I solve this??

Any help will be appreciated.

## Update:

Somebody give me a solution here in the answers, and it worked good, but I made some edits on it, like this:

```
getSubscriber() {
    return _subscribersCollectionRef
        .orderBy('Register date', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
          subscriberModel.clear();
      for (var element in event.docs) {
        subscriberModel.add(SubscriberModel.fromMap(element));
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: hmmmm have you tried not using bindStream actually on the getSubscribers inside is already streamed by snapshot so you dont need to bind them but only add data also snapshot.map is not a listenable data stream but use snapshots().listen instead.

Comment: @ArbiterChil thanks, but it doesn't work when I cancel the bind (cancel and edit the code to suit the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class AddSubscriberController extends GetxController {

final CollectionReference _subscribersCollectionRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Subscribers');


  final List<SubscriberModel> subscriberModel = <SubscriberModel>[].obs;


 @override
  void onInit() {
    getSubscribers();
    super.onInit();
    
  }


   getSubscribers() {
    return _subscribersCollectionRef
        .orderBy('Register date', descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
         //// try to simple approach 
        for (var x in event.docs) {
           final Map<String, dynamic> y = x.data();
           final tojson = SubscriberModel.fromJson(y);
           subscriberModel.add(tojson); 
      }
      
    });
  }
}
```

for the view

```
class View extends StatelessWidget {
  const View ({super.key});

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final controller =  Get.put(AddSubscriberController());

  return Obx(
()=> Scaffold(
  body : ListView.builder(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: controller.subscriberModel.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             final item = controller.subscriberModel[index];
              return buildSubInfo(
                name: item.firstName,
                lastName: item.lastName,
                father:item.father,
                area: item.area,
                counterNo: item.counterNumber,
                date: item.date,
              );
            },
          ),
));
}
```

try this if this work

Comment: Thank you so much, It went good,  but I edit some thing in your code, I will add it as an update to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
GetX<AddSubscriberController>(builder : (controller) {         
          return ListView.builder(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: controller.subscribers.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return buildSubInfo(
                name: controller.subscribers[index].firstName,
                lastName: controller.subscribers[index].lastName,
                father: controller.subscribers[index].father,
                area: controller.subscribers[index].area,
                counterNo: controller.subscribers[index].counterNumber,
                date: controller.subscribers[index].date,
              );
            },
          );
        }),
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but ofcourse I tried GetX widget instead Obx before I put the question..
But unfortunately it gave me the same result.