# Display updated value everytime button is press firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

i am trying to displaying the new value every time the user click the button but it keeps displaying the old data. I need to hot restart to see the new data after i update it. I do not know what i did wrong because i am still learning. This is my full code. I hope someone can help me because i am stuck here 3 hours +

```
TextEditingController _reloadEditingController = new TextEditingController();

  int balance = 0;
  late int s = int.parse(_reloadEditingController.text);

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String? name;
  String email = '';
  String phoneNumber = '';
  String imageUrl = '';
  String joinedAt = '';
  String location = '';


  void reload() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(widget.userID)
        .update({"balance": balance + s});
  }

  void getUserData() async {
    try {
      _isLoading = true;
      final DocumentSnapshot userDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(widget.userID)
          .get();

      if (userDoc == null) {
        return;
      } else {
        setState(() {
          name = userDoc.get('name');
          email = userDoc.get('email');
          phoneNumber = userDoc.get('phoneNumber');
          imageUrl = userDoc.get('userImage');
          location = userDoc.get('location');
          balance = userDoc.get('balance');
        });
        final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
        User? user = _auth.currentUser;
        final _uid = user!.uid;
        setState(() {
          _isSameUser = _uid == widget.userID;
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
    } finally {
      _isLoading = false;
    }
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal[300],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Wallet'),
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            color: Colors.teal[300],
          ),
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
                final User? user = _auth.currentUser;
                final String uid = user!.uid;

                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (_) => ProfileScreen(
                              userID: uid,
                            )));
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, size: 40, color: Colors.white)),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 300,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      color: Color(0xFF006e6e)),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            name!,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Balance",
                              
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),

                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'RM',
                              
                            ),

                            Container(


                                child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                                  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                      .collection('users')
                                      .doc(widget.userID)
                                      .get(),
                                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                      return Center(
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                      );
                                    }
                                    return Text(balance.toString());
                                  },
                                ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),


                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text("Reload your E-Wallet",
)
                          ],
                        ),

                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Form(
                              key: _formKey,
                              child: Expanded(
                                child: TextFormField(

                                  controller: _reloadEditingController,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,

                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                Container(
                  width: 320,
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      reload();
                    },

                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Reload E-Wallet",

                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
```

Comment: could you add your full code ?

Comment: done , i already add the full code

Comment: If you want to listen for updates to the data, you'll need to use `snapshots()` instead of `get()`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart Also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74248243/flutter-stream-is-not-updating-data-automatically-only-after-hot-reload/74248575#74248575

Answer (score 1):

You need yo call `getUserData` when you update your data so change your `reload` to this:

```
void reload() async {
    int s = int.parse(_reloadEditingController.text); // define this hear
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(widget.userID)
        .update({"balance": balance + s});

    setState(() {});
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, i really appreciate it , you are my savior but now it keep adding the same value that the first time i input maybe something is wrong with my form.

Comment: the reason you get the same value is that you are not changing balance, you update your data with same value you get before

Comment: no it is not, is this the balance controller? _reloadEditingController?

Comment: i dont quite understand, isnt the balance should add up with whatever value that i have pass through controller? For example : i have balance 100 , and i input into the textformfield 100, the balance should update to 200 (its working) but then when i input textformfield to 200 , the balance should be update to 400 but it still adding the balance by 100 so i need to hot restart to add another value . Sorry for asking to much and troubling you

Comment: I updated my answer again. please check again,. @luffy

Comment: its working now dude , thank you and i love you !!

Answer (score 0):

Solution of this problem depends on Stream, because you want the live data.

You want to upload data and download it for show in the UI.

If you try to use StreamBuilder instead of FutureBuilder, I think it may be help..

For me I use GetX package, and since a while I faced the same problem, I will put the URL for my question and see if you can take an idea..

[Flutter: live stream with getx has a problem, it shows data without updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73961859/flutter-live-stream-with-getx-has-a-problem-it-shows-data-without-updating)